# PHPMyAdmin Export Import Error 1064

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm getting a tad frustrated here trying to export my database from my Macbook Localhost to my Windows Localhost.

I have exported from PHPMyAdmin (v 4.1.14) on my Mac and imported (v 4.1.14) on my Windows machine and I keep getting an error:

```
--
-- Stand-in structure for view `overall_team_ppi`
--
CREATE TABLE `overall_team_ppi` (
);

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7
```

--
The cod it is running:

```
CREATE TABLE `1415fixtures` (
`season` varchar(5)
,`date` varchar(10)
,`T1ID` double
,`hometeam` varchar(20)
,`T2ID` double
,`awayteam` varchar(20)
);
```

It's frustrating that the same software cannot export / import to itself correctly.

Any idea on what the error is on the below code, and how can I resolve this confrontation between PHPMyAdmin and itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You received this error because your table does not contains any columns.

A table must have at least 1 column.

Check how looks table `overall_team_ppi` on Mac MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, I must be going blind.